# Unchecking a radio box without use of id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm setting up a table, where each row will contain several radio boxes. There are certain conditions for the radio boxes, for example:

If "Home" is checked, the "Text" radio box will be unchecked and "Voice" will be checked instead (ie. You can't text a home phone number). Similarly, when "Home" and "Voice" are checked, clicking "Text" will force "Home" to be unchecked and "Cell" will become checked.

I can get this working fine for one instance, with the use of .getElementById and the click function, but where I run into trouble is when things are scaled up. This table might have 20 or 30 rows, each of which containing a cell with these radio boxes.

I'm not great with jQuery, so I'm not sure how to make a more general version, so that each set of radio boxes are their own contained units, so to speak. I made a jsfiddle where you can see that only the first instance is working, likely because I am targeting the boxes using their id and you can't have two elements with the same id... help? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/3uHqS/

Script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('contact-home').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('format-voice').checked = true;
    };

    document.getElementById('format-text').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('contact-cell').checked = true;
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="" id="contact-cell" />
    <label for="contact-cell">Cell</label>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="" id="contact-home" />
    <label for="contact-home">Home</label>
    <input type="radio" name="format" value="" id="format-voice" />
    <label for="format-voice">Voice</label>
    <input type="radio" name="format" value="" id="format-text" />
    <label for="format-text">Text</label>
</form>
```

Comment: You're repeating IDs, they must be unique.

Comment: Sounds like you need a widget-like element for which you can define logic once and reuse it anywhere on the page.

Comment: Use 'this' and classes. It should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to assign every radio box a descriptive class like 'text-radio' or 'home-radio'. Then when you need to change all of the Text radio boxes you do something like the following in jQuery:

```
$(".text-radio").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this affect every radio box in the class? Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but each group of radio boxes has to be unique, so that clicking on a radio box in one row won't affect other radio boxes in the next, separate row.

Comment: Ah sorry I misinterpreted your question. In this case you would want to then access the radiobox by the row id $("tr#rowid .text-radio"). Or if you just have an instance of the clicked radiobutton what you can do is get the parent of the radiobutton then search through the parents children for the specific radiobuttons you need to edit.